# How can I test if a Java object is an enum in scala?

Tags: java, scala

I have a method which converts a string to an int and a Java enum to an int. For other data types, it doesn't do any conversion.

```
def myConverter[T](attributeValue: T) = {
  if (attributeValue.isInstanceOf[String]) {
    attributeValue.asInstanceOf[String].toInt
  } else if (attributeValue.isInstanceOf[Enumeration$Value]) {
    CodeReferenceEx.toInteger(attributeValue.asInstanceOf[Enumeration$Value])
  } else {
    attributeValue
  }
}
```

The method never enters the `elseif` block (`Enumeration$Value`) because the condition is always evaluated to false. I am using a java enumeration object.

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks

Comment: `Enumeration#Value` is for Scala enum objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a Java enum:

```
public enum C {
    ONE, TWO
}
```

And a Scala enum:

```
object E extends Enumeration {
  val A = Value
}
```

The following works for both:

```
def myConverter[T](attributeValue: T) = {
  attributeValue match {
    case str: String =>
      str.toInt
    case _: Enumeration =>
      println("Scala Enum!")
    case _: Enumeration#Value =>
      println("Scala Enumeration Value!")
    case _ if attributeValue.getClass.isEnum =>
      println("Java Enum!")
    case _ => println("oops")
  }
}
```

---

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  myConverter(E)
  myConverter(E.A)
  myConverter(C.ONE)
}
```

Yields:

```
Scala Enum!
Scala Enumeration Value!
Java Enum!
```

Comment: Which version of Scala have you used to test it?

Comment: @pcejrowski If I recall correctly, 2.11.8 and Java 1.8.0_121

Answer (score 0):

For java enum cast to `java.lang.Enum`